# $GITHUB_ENV process.env cannot be obtained

Tags: github, action, cicd

` - name: Get version
run: echo "TAG_VERSION=${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

```
  - name: Get git head
    run: echo "GIT_HEAD=${GITHUB_SHA}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

  - name: Gen npmrc
    run: echo "//registry.npmjs.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.NPM_PUBLISH_TOKEN }}" >> ./.npmrc

  - name: Build&publish
    run: sh ./scripts/publish.sh
    env:
      NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_PUBLISH_TOKEN}}
      TAG_VERSION: ${{env.TAG_VERSION}}
      GIT_HEAD: ${{env.GIT_HEAD}}
      REGISTRY: https://registry.npmjs.com/
      FORCE_COLOR: 2
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      NODE_OPTIONS: --max-old-space-size=4096
```

`

`console.log(process.env.TAG_VERSION)  //undefind console.log(process.env.GIT_HEAD)  //undefind`

Can be obtained normally
`console.log(process.env.TAG_VERSION)   console.log(process.env.GIT_HEAD)`